# ¿Cómo definir el número de semana en fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Buenas, estoy trabajando con el plugin de fullcalendar, quiero saber si es posible definirle en la vista de semana, la semana que yo deseo; por ejemplo: la semana número 27, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar moment para calcular la fecha para el nº de semana:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var currentDate = moment().day("Monday").week(27);

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'basicWeek',
        defaultDate: currentDate
    });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: Me funciono perfecto, gracias Asier.